Why is the transfer of a phosphoryl group used by ATP to drive reactions rather than simple hydrolysis?
I’ve been thinking a lot about ATP, and here’s what I’m thinking so far:
It seems like ATP can do work via hydrolysis, where an enzyme will manoeuvre a water molecule so that the last phosphoryl group is no longer bonded to ADP. Then, the phosphate and ADP repel each other strongly, which can change the enzyme’s shape.
ATP also commonly transfers phosphoryl groups. It seems like there’s still a strong repelling force between ADP and Pi, which enables the phosphoryl group to be pushed onto a molecule. The work done is converted to potential energy in the molecule. Now that the molecule has a higher potential energy, it is able to proceed in reactions that previously would have needed an “input of energy,” like the force produced by ATP hydrolysis or heat.

Would reactions driven by phosphoryl group transfer also be feasible through ATP hydrolysis alone (e.g., could ATP hydrolysis force two reactants together in an enzyme's active site)?
If so, why is phosphoryl group transfer preferred as a mechanism for enabling subsequent reactions rather than ATP hydrolysis alone?
Why is the phosphoryl group in particular widely used to ensure the progression of cellular reactions, rather than some other group?


Please review the comment under your last post; finishing the tour would be helpful, as would reading the help section about asking. It's standard on this site to ask one question per post; also expected is evidence of research (a quote and a link) attempting to answer your own question. What you're thinking may not be correct, and framing it that way is an invitation to discussion.  For many reasons, "Why doesn't it happen [this way]" questions are generally not very well met here. Biology is more the study of what is than what is not and why it is not so.

As a Christmas present I decided to provide you and the List with an answer to one of your questions. I had to edit your question to retract my downvote, although I personally would scrap point 3 in your list and ask a specific question on this point. I have ignored it as it took enough space to answer the main question.

Answer Summary
There are two distinct questions here:
Q1 “Could ATP hydrolysis force two reactants together in an enzyme’s active site?”
A1 No. Reaction coupling always involves formation of an ‘activated’ intermediate comprising the phosphoryl or adenosyl component of ATP and one of the substrates. This, or a subsequent activated intermediate, combines with the other substrate in a subsequent step.
The suggestion reveals a relatively common ignorance of the way that ATP can be used to drive ‘non-spontaneous’ reactions. My answer will address this point.
Q2 “Why is the phosphate group in particular widely used to ensure the progression of cellular reactions…?”
A2 This is an aspect of the question “Why is ATP used as energy currency?”, which has already been asked on this site in various forms, one of which I have already answered, and another with a relevant answer from someone else. I shall not address it here.
General Answer 
I will start by reminding the reader that it is the free energy change in a reaction that determines whether it proceeds, irrespective of whether it is enzyme-catalysed or not. I have already considered this aspect of ATP hydrolysis in the answer to a previous, related, question.
A ‘black-box’ approach is valid in relation to the thermodynamics of whether ATP can drive an unfavourable/non-spontaneous reaction, but a mechanistic approach is required to answer the question of how ATP hydrolysis can be ‘coupled’ to an overall reaction such as:
ATP + X + Y → ADP + Pi + X–Y
The answer is that ATP reacts with one of the substrates to form a ‘high free-energy’ intermediate that can then react with the second substrate. In the above case we can represent this as:
ADP~P + X  → ADP + X~P
…followed by
X~P + Y  → X~Y + Pi
with the ‘~’ symbol being used as a crude representation of the bonds made or broken in the transfer of ‘energy’†.
The crux of the matter is that ADP and inorganic phosphate are never released in the same reaction step, as the overall reaction might suggest. There is no trimolecular reaction.
The schema emphasizes that what is important is the bonds being formed, not the phosphate group or phosphoryl transfer. Indeed the alternative manner in which ATP drives reactions does not involve phosphoryl transfer, but transfer of AMP to give an acyl adenylate intermediate:
AMP~PP + X  → PPi + X~AMP
…followed by 
X~AMP + Y  → X~Y + AMP
In instances of the second type — where the intermediates are generally more easily demonstrated — one often reads that the substrate X is ‘activated’ so as to be able to drive the subsequent reaction. The term ‘activation’ applies equally well to instances of the second type.
Although important, the mechanistic details of the formation and reaction of these activated intermediates on the enzyme will not be covered here — they vary from enzyme to enzyme — and would require a question of their own. Studying them would dispel the idea that electrostatic repulsion (obviously not between ADP and Pi) is somehow the key to ATP coupling.
Examples
Examples of synthetic reactions coupled to the overall hydrolysis ATP are now considered, in order to illustrate and provide evidence for the proposition above. I challenge the reader to provide any example of a reaction which violates this proposition.
(1a) Glutamine formation from glutamate and ammonia

In the first phase of this reaction (catalysed by glutamine synthetase) an acyl phosphate is formed, which then reacts with ammonia to form the carbon–nitrogen bond of the amide. In fact this is an example of general reaction scheme involving an acyl phosphate intermediate shared by members of the so-called ATP-grasp superfamily that also includes glutathione synthetase, D-Ala-D-Ala ligase, and succinyl-CoA synthetase:

[From a 2012 review by Waldrop et al. For glutamine synthase both R′ and R″ are H.]
(1b) Carboxylation reactions
There are several reactions (e.g. pyruvate carboxylase) in which ATP drives the addition of carbon dioxide to a compound via an intermediate in which the carbon dioxide is covalently bound to the co-enzyme, biotin, through a bond the breakage of which has a negative free energy change. In effect the energetic potential of ATP has been transferred to carboxy-biotin, and this is thought to proceed through the formation of a carboxyphosphate intermediate:

The initial reaction is complex, involving another cofactor, acetyl-CoA, but I mention this class of enzymes, not only to reinforce the idea of transfer of ‘bond energy’ through phosphoryl intermediates, but because the ultimate reaction of the carboxy-biotin with the other substrate takes place on another site (actually another subunit) of the enzyme.
(2a) Asparagine formation from aspartate and ammonia

Here the AMP is transferred to the substrate, with the other phosophoanydride bond being hydrolysed and pyrophosphate liberated. Reaction with ammonia does not occur until the second phase of the reaction. Another metabolic pathway in which adenylate transfer occurs is fatty acid synthesis.
(2b) Amino acid activation for peptide bond formation
Transitory reaction intermediates in an enzyme-catalysed reaction are often difficult to identify, and this may be the reason for some of the initial ‘magic’ thinking about ATP. But a type of reaction in which adenylate transfer occurs and the intermediate product was identified quite early on, is the ‘activation’ of amino acids by the aminoacyl-tRNA synthetases. The energy potential of the phosphoanhydride bond is maintained in this intermediate and the subsequent bond between the amino acid and the tRNA, which will be used on the ribosome to form a peptide bond.

Conclusion
A sledgehammer to crack a nut? Perhaps. But the topic of how the free energy of hydrolysis of ATP is coupled to synthetic reactions is seldom considered outside biochemical texts, and perhaps not given sufficient emphasis even there. Popular accounts tend to ignore thermodynamics or chemistry for cartoon explosions, and students coming from the more numeric sciences tend to think on a higher plane. The latter is typified by a poster on
SE Physics who had arrived at the idea that breakage of the phosphoanhydride bond released “electromagnetic energy at some characteristic frequency which bonds in the enzyme could absorb, hence changing its shape”.  He would probably react to this answer as John Ruskin is said to have done on discovering that his bride had pubic hair.
† Although to some the ‘~’ may recall Lipmann’s ‘squiggle’, it is here used solely to allow the reader to follow the bonds formed following the initial breakage of a phosphoanhydride bond in ATP. Lipmann’s ‘squiggle’ would certainly not apply to the final product, for which emphasizing a single bond may also be an over-simplification.
